# TdLoadingService not showing loading spinner

Tags: teradata-covalent

I'm trying to overlay a loading spinner using the Teradata / covalent UI kit, as shown in [this example](https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/loading), however it simply won't show, no matter what I try.
I've put together a single use [example here](https://github.com/thrixton/covalent-loadingservice), any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to load the SCSS styles for the loading spinner to appear. I [recreated your example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ajc-stackoverflow-48662341?file=styles.scss) and was able to have the spinner load correctly. The Angular-CLI might not be compiling your `theme.scss` because it is in the assets folder.

Comment: Amazing, thank you. I'll have to dig through to pick it all apart, where did you get the style.scss from, I obviously missed a heap in my example which I copied from the getting started guide (not to mention if it wasn't being applied)

Comment: You're welcome! The scss is from the [Covalent Stackblitz Template](https://stackblitz.com/edit/covalent?file=theme.scss).

Comment: Had a look through it with my glasses on and I was importing from @covalent/core instead of @covalent/core/loading, that managed to fix it all, thanks again :)